# Execute stored function without knowing registerOutParameter In JAVA

Tags: java, stored-functions, callable-statement

I'm calling a stored function but i don't know the return type of the function. It can be `NUMBER,VARCHAR,CURSOR` or `DATE`. so I don't know the `registerOutParameter()` type. help me out to resolve the problem

```
CallableStatement cstmt = connection.prepareCall("{call ?:= MyFunctionName('value1','value2')}");
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.?); // here 
cstmt.execute();
```

Demo stored-function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IDK.MyFunctionName(param1 VARCHAR2, param2 VARCHAR2) 
RETURN NUMBER 
AS 
  V_FLAG NUMBER;
BEGIN 
  V_FLAG := 5;
  RETURN V_FLAG;
END;
```

Comment: look at the Demo stored-function, the functions return type is number , so I have to provide OracleTypes.NUMBER in cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, here); in this case i don't know the return type of the desired function. that's why can't provide registerOutParameter before execute CallableStatement.